# how can I make sure that control + c don't kill the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I used a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asnXWOUKhTA) to create a minimal linux distro, but if I do ctrl + c the kernel crash!

EDIT: I was confused, when I do ctrl + d

Comment: The "kernel" doesn't respond to ctrl+c. We'd need to know a lot more about what's happening to help out. What is the foreground process when you type ctrl+c? What exactly is the behavior that you see (instead of "crash", tell us the specific error message that you see, etc).

Comment: I'm _guessing_ the foreground process was PID 1 and decided to exit upon INT. The kernel will panic if it loses PID 1. What is the panic message? Is it something like "attempted to kill init"?

Comment: What's up with all the downvotes? The person is learning Linux/Unix, did you know everything about Linux from the get go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is exactly what happens in your linked tutorial starting from the 44:00 point:

[The tutorial from 44:00 onwards](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxwanV94-7uc8hTAUt6laYXgLn6emsVoSu)

The tutorial uses a minimal shell script as `/init`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t devtmpfs udev /dev
sysctl -w kernel.printk="2 4 1 7"
/bin/sh
```

During the tutorial, a line that adds `poweroff -f` as the last line of `/init` was added to the script that creates the initrd file, but the initrd was not actually updated to contain that command.

As PID #1 will be a shell executing the script, and the `/bin/sh` that displays the root prompt will be its child process, the PID #1 shell will be waiting for `/bin/sh` to exit, and once it does, PID #1 will exit too. After that, there will be no longer any processes left; and as others have noted in the comments, the loss of PID #1 will make the kernel very unhappy. This will cause a kernel panic, with the message:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

(In this case, it's not so much that `init` was killed, but that it actually exited on its own. PID #1 is not generally supposed to just exit without either shutting down the system or providing a valid successor for itself.)

There are also other indications that this "minimal Linux distro" is a very rudimentary toy setup. When `/bin/sh` starts, it says:

```
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

This indicates `/bin/sh` is not running in a properly set-up console session, and won't be able to react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keystrokes in the usual way. Instead, on receiving a Ctrl-C, the `/bin/sh` will just exit like a regular shell command - and after that, the `/init` script has reached end-of-file and so the shell running the script (as PID #1) will exit too.

Ctrl-D may end up having the same effect, as it is the standard Unix End-Of-File keystroke: normally the TTY driver detects Ctrl-D and converts it into an End-of-File condition, but since the shell here said `can't access tty`, it might be detecting the Ctrl-D on its own. Basically, the shell will interpret the End-Of-File condition on standard input as "the user got disconnected somehow" and so the shell will exit... causing PID #1 script to reach its end.

To develop this "minimal Linux distro" further, one of the first steps would be to have the `/init` script replace itself with a process that fulfills the requirements of working as PID #1:

- ideally never exiting, but perhaps with ability to `exec()` a new version of itself to enable updates
- proper initialization of console session and any other configured TTYs (possibly by monitoring that there is always a process associated with those, and starting a `getty` process for them if it finds the console or a configured TTY without any live processes)
- reaping of orphaned zombies: PID #1 should spend most of its time in `wait(-1)`ing for SIGCHLD signals from orphaned processes, for which the kernel will assign PID #1 as their PPID. Whenever such an orphaned process dies, the `wait()` will read its result code, and once that is done, the kernel will be able to clean up the dead process from its process table, so it won't hang around as a zombie.

This might be achieved by adding a suitable configuration for [BusyBox `/bin/init`](https://www.halolinux.us/embedded-systems/busybox-init.html) to the initrd file, and replacing the last line of `/init` with:

```
exec /bin/init
```

The `exec` here is important: it causes the shell that's currently running the `/init` script as PID #1 to replace itself with `/bin/init`, by omitting the `fork()` system call before `exec()`ing the new binary. As a result, the PID number will not change, and the `/bin/init` will be able to assume its role as the true PID #1.

Comment: can I set a custom action for ctrl + d?

Comment: You would need to first unset the default "ctrl + d = End-of-File" functionality, and since this configuration apparently does not use the TTY driver in the normal way, that might be difficult. You might try replacing the `/bin/sh` line in the `/init` script with `/bin/sh -I`, to put the shell into `ignoreeof` mode. After that, ctrl + d might be assignable just like a regular keystroke.

Comment: _PID #1 is not generally supposed to just exit without either shutting down the system or providing a valid successor for itself._ – I don't think it's _ever_ supposed to exit. The system shuts down without it exiting (i.e. the function that removes `task_struct` is never called. And when it provides a successor for itself, it just uses `execve()` so it never really exits (the PID never changes).